# Object access returns an "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error with type guard

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function that checks if two strings are anagrams, I mapped their letters and the count of their occurrence inside an object with type `Record<string, number | undefined>`. But when I try to access a property it throws an `Object is possibly 'undefined'"` error even with type guard. I'm curious to know why typescript is throwing such error.

The function:

```
function validAnagram(string1: string, string2: string): boolean {
    if (string1.length !== string2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    const string1Map: Record<string, number | undefined> = {};

    // Map string1 letters and their occurrences
    for (let idx = 0; idx <= string1.length; idx += 1) {
        const key: string = string1[idx];
        string1Map[key] = (string1Map[key] ?? 0) + 1;
    }

    // Compare string2 to string1Map
    for (let idx = 0; idx <= string2.length; idx += 1) {
        const key: string = string2[idx];

        // Exit if letter is undefined or 0
        if (string1Map[key] === undefined || string1Map[key] === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        string1Map[key]! -= 1; // "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since you typed the value of your map as `string | undefined`, it is either a `string` or `undefined` and TypeScript therefore gives you the error that the object my be undefined.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann The question is why the type guard just above (that is supposed to filter out `undefined`) does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit unfortunate that Typescript cannot deal with type guards that involve property access like this one. An easy way to fix it is to write the contents of your `for` loop like this:

```
        const letter = string1Map[key];
        // Exit if letter is undefined or 0
        if (letter === undefined || letter === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        string1Map[key] = letter - 1;
```

This way, Typescript can correctly narrow the type of `letter` as it is an independent variable.